# Plesk login page will not load --"ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Tags: authentication, server, plesk

my school has instructed me to use a plesk server to host a website on building. the plesk homepage i was told to use was https://{mystudentidentifier}.tt284.open.ac.uk. when i use these credentials i get sent to the plesk default web server as it cant find the adress i have entered.

however when i click to icon that takes me to the login page the page doesn't load. i get this error "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". my school is not giving me any advice but they assure me that my account and therefore my server does exist and is running.

trouble shooting step i tried

my internet connection is fine
clearing the browser cache did not work
trying a different browser did not work
trying to load the page on my phone didn't work
my firewall is already off and i don't run any antivirus software
i was unable to ping the address successfully

any advice would be much appreciated.